# Wann verwendet man – abgesehen vom Diktat von Zahlen – „zwo“ anstatt „zwei“?

Tags: numbers

[Wikionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zwo) sagt *zwo* sei zu verwenden, um die Zahlen zwei und drei deutlich zu unterscheiden. Vermutlich wegen der gemeinsamen Endung *ei*. Auch ist da zu lesen, dass *zwo*, als die weibliche Form für *zwei*, fast in die Vergessenheit geraten sei. (Wenn das nicht ganz genau stimmt, bitte ein Beispiel erwähnen.)

- Abgesehen vom Diktat von Zahlen, welche andere Verwendung für *zwo* existiert?

Comment: Links, zwo, drei, vier!

Comment: Bei der vierten Wiederholung von „Zwei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass”. *Entschuldigt meine Albernheit.*

Comment: Ich weiß nicht genau, was alles unter »Diktat von Zahlen« zu verstehen ist, aber in automatischen Bahnhofsdurchsagen hört man »Gleis Zwo« statt »Gleis Zwei«.

Comment: Im Schweizerdeutschen wird die weibliche Form von älteren Personen manchmal noch verwendet. *Zwo Fraue*, aber *zwe Mane*.

Comment: Es ist auch in Deutschland regional noch verbreitet, nicht unbedingt mit der ursprünglichen Kasuszuordnung.

Comment: Jedes Mal, wenn sich etwas auf -o reimen muss, wenn *zwei* und *drei* gerade schon mal unklar waren, oder wenn man im bairischen Dialekt (*zwoa*) spricht. ;) Abgesehen davon sollte die Frage ggf geschlossen sein wegen *too broad*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In der deutschen Funksprache wird ausschließlich die zwo verwendet.

Und zwar um zu verhindern, dass wichtige Daten, wie Flugzeugkennungen oder Landewinkel falsch ankommen.

Bsp.:

> Echo-Delta-Zwo-Fünf in der Landeschleife eins

Comment: "Ich dachte du kommst um zwei?!" - "Hmm, ich habe 'drei' verstanden."

Comment: @MartinPfeffer  Aber wer würde denn "ich dachte, du kommst um zwo" sagen? Ich meine fast, "zwo" noch nie bei Uhrzeiten gehört zu haben.

Comment: Das sagt Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwei#Kardinalzahl 'Mit dem Aufkommen elektronischer Sprechverbindungen (Telefon und Sprechfunk) bürgerte sich die Form zwo für zwei ein, um bei schlechter Übertragungsqualität das Wort besser vom ähnlich lautenden „drei“ unterscheiden zu können.'