# How often is 'zwo' actually used in place of 'zwei'

Tags: numbers

Just starting learning German and a number of texts I've read say that 'zwei' takes on a morphological change to 'zwo' in spoken speech to differentiate with 'drei'. How often do people actually use this alternative in everyday speech, or is this one of those textbook 'Good to know!' asides that actually only live within the confines of textbook pages?

Comment: It is important to know that R2-D2 from Star Wars always has two "zwo"s and no "zwei". Here the "zwo" is mandatory! ;-)

Comment: Wikipedia backs you up on this, but I would have called him Err-Zwei-De-Zwei without batting an eyelid... Of course I only ever saw the movies in English.

Comment: ''Zwo'' is definitely more common than ''fünnef'' (5) and it’s more likely to be used with digits than with numbers. It’s also canonical in some places that already have been mentioned, most notably ''links, zwo, drei, vier''.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/wann-verwendet-man-abgesehen-vom-diktat-von-zahlen-zwo-anstatt-zwei

Comment: @Ingmar  Ich habe - außer einem Artikel im "Stern", als der erste Starwars-Film herauskam, wenig von diesen Filmen mitbekommen, aber ich hätte auch schlichtweg Ahr-Tuh-Die-Tuh gesagt, einfach weil man Namen ja in der Regel nicht übersetzt. Cowboy John im Western wird selten zum Kuhhirten Johannes in der deutschen Synchronfassung.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann:Ja und nein. Hier ist es eine Art Typennummer, die wird man wohl ohne große Probleme übersetzen können. Schlimmer ist es zB bei literarischen Übersetzungen, wo mir "Korporal Karotte" (orig: Corporal Carrot) oder "Grinsi Kleinpo" (orig: Cheery Littlebottom. I'm not making this up!) die Lust an Übersetzungen und Synchroniserungen nachhaltig ausgetrieben haben.

Comment: @Ingmar: Diese Typennummern (R2D2 und C3PO) wurden wohl gewählt, weil sie in Englisch ziemlich gut klingen. Artuditu klingt niedlich, Sithripio klingt "shakespearisch"-klassisch und irgendwie gebildet. Das geht in der Übersetzung total verloren. Es passt zu den Erscheinungen: R2D2 pfeift niedlich, C3PO spricht gebildetes Englisch.

Comment: @Ingmar: Grinsi Kleinpo (hatte ich noch nicht gehört, denn auch in den deutschen Übersetzungen der Scheibenwelt-Bücher heißen die Cheery LittleBottom und Carrot, soweit ich weiß) oder Korporal Karotte klingen absolut falsch. Grausige Übersetzung.

Comment: How often? Zwo mal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Aber ja doch, die Namen der Scheibenwelt werden fast alle übersetzt (?), von "Kommandant Mumm" (im Original: Vimes) und seiner Frau "Lady Käsedick" (Ramkin) bis hin zum Armbrust-Fabrikanten "Starkimarm" (Stronginthearm) und vielen anderen. Nur Nobbs und Colon bleiben unübersetzt, da konnte man sich wohl zwischen Dickdarm und Doppelpunkt nicht entscheiden. Für Zweisprachige einigermaßen grausam zu lesen.

Comment: @Ingmar: habe mich gerade mal umgeschaut. Die paar deutschen Ausgaben die ich habe sind meistens über die Hexen und sonst nur noch "Helle Barden". Und da steht tatsächlich "Korporal Karotte" und "Hauptmann Mumm" drin. Ich bin entsetzt und frage mich, warum mir das nie aufgefallen ist. Aber das ist wahrscheinlich, weil das die ersten Bücher waren, die ich gekauft und gelesen habe. Später dann nur noch Originale. Bin trotzdem entsetzt!

Comment: The Swiss solution is to pronounce drei as [try] (*truu*), as in [xliːs try] for *Gleis drei*, which also avoids disambiguation :-)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "weil man Namen ja in der Regel nicht übersetzt. Cowboy John im Western wird selten zum Kuhhirten Johannes in der deutschen Synchronfassung." - das hängt stark vom Genre ab. Im Fantasy-Bereich bzw. mittelalterlich anmutenden Kontexten sind Übersetzungen von Namen durchaus verbreiteter (vgl. Bilbo Beutlin vs. Bilbo Baggins).

Comment: I hear "zwo" used regularly in everyday speech. I live in Lörrach, at the southwestern tip of Germany. It was actuallly quite confusing to me at first, since I did *not* learn this variant in class.

Comment: I just became aware of this usage on a 2020 YouTube video (see at 5:57 - 6:36): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5v5kmLp0HA

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Above all, it's good to know. Speaking for Austria, it's not very common in spoken language (any more -- used to be much more frequent), unless you are on the telephone, say, and want to make extra certain that no mistakes are made. It's routinely used in radio communications, too, much like the English "niner".

Personally I use it for important things like a phone number, bank account or credit card number, things like that. It's definitely used, but not as common as you might think.

Answer (score 14):

From my understanding, "zwo" is a replacement for the correct "zwei" that has emerged and became relatively widespread when telephones and radio communication were introduced because with bad signal quality affecting especially consonants, "zwei" might easily be confused with "drei".

I would suppose that part of it becoming widespread was through the military. Also it became common in business communication (offices) because of the growing importance of communication via telephone.

However, it never made it into everyday and standard language. (In everyday language perhaps by way of contamination from military and office use.) You would never write "zwo", or if you did, readers would ask themselves what's wrong with you.

There might be regions in Germany where "zwo" is part of an oral regiolect. I would intuitively locate this somewhere in the Middle-North-West of today's Germany, but I may be wrong about this. I would not see it related to the Bavarian "zwoa", because the change of vocals from "zwei" to "zwoa" is systematic in Bavarian, see *Eichhörnchen* --> "Oachkatzl", *meinst du* --> "moanst", *du weißt* --> "woast". I think where people in Bavaria say "zwo" they took this from the telecommunications habits described above. But actually I have never heard a Bavarian say "zwo", and quite logically so, because due to their anyway existing "zwoa" they have no need of using an artificial word to differentiate *zwei* from *drei*.

Comment: In my practice, I sometimes have problems properly hearing the difference between "eins", "zwei" or "drei" (I guess my hearing is slightly impaired by the high frequency of the drills), so I taught them to say "eins", "zwo", "drü" (like the Swiss team in Cool Runnings). Works for me.

Comment: Same as with "Juno" and "Julei", I guess: to better stress the difference between the two similar names.

Comment: Zwo is not "a replacement for the correct zwei" , nor is it "artificial". Zwo is historically the feminine of zwei, cognate with the English "two" and similar forms in other Germanic and Indo-European languages. In referring to a feminine noun, zwei is a "replacement" of the "correct" zwo..

Comment: @fdb Why not write an official answer?

Answer (score 5):

I first ran into this when, as serving with the US Army in Germany in 1995. I listened to a Polizei transmit a number 27262 as zwo, sieben, zwo, sechs, zwo. In my broken German, I asked him why zwo and not zwei and he explained they used zwo for all radio communications to clearly differentiate from drei and then went on to point out that we NATO use FIFE instead of five and NINER instead of nine.

Answer (score 1):

That's dependent of the Region.

As you may know in German there are more Dialects than in English.

In the southern 'states' (e.g. Bavaria) `zwo` or `zwoa` or even `zwaa` (but `zwaa` more in Austria) are used pretty often (sometimes people use only `zwo` or `zwoa`). In the northern parts of Germany most people use `zwei`.

Comment: Zwa(a) is used in Austrian dialects, too, not more. "Zwo" is not originally Bavarian. Zwoa and zwa(a) are.

Comment: But we use mainly zwo and zwoa.

Comment: Are you from western Bavaria?

Comment: nope 'Oberpfalz'

Comment: It's not a dialekt thing, afaik.

Comment: It's also used for voice radio traffic (where the reason to differentiate it from "drei" actually matters, otherwise this no reason to use it at all. English uses "niner" and "fower" for the same reason), and in expressions like "links, zwo, drei, vier".

Comment: Also, if you address somebody by last name (in the military, say, at work, or wherever) and it's a very common one the second bearer of that name will usually be addressed as "Müller Zwo" or similar.

Comment: “in German there are more Dialects than in English” – that’s a claim that probably won’t stand any review, even if you applied a very narrow definition of _dialect_ to English and a very broad one to German.

Comment: "Zwo" is definitely not used / very uncommon in Bavaria. "Zwoa" etc. is a whole different story.

Comment: Zwo is northern, not southern.  This internet is full of crap, no eels.

Answer (score 1):

Heard it in Germany at train stations, it is used to announce the train number, at least in automated messages.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bundeswehr, use of zwo when counting is definitely still common, although it might be dependent on region.

Comment: Yes, getting the feeling that this is very much a regional thing. Playing it by ear dependant on where you are in Germany appears to be the key!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other stuff mentioned above, "zwo" is a term used in the classical german card game of "Skat", where it is used in the first phase of the game.