# Wo kommt "Links-zwo-drei-vier" her?

Tags: expression, proverb

In einer aktuellen Frage hier wurde der Marschierspruch "Links-zwo-drei-vier" zitiert. Ich begann mich zu fragen, wo der Vers herkommt.

Nun, klar, aus dem Militärischen, wenn die beteiligten Personen gehalten sind, ihre fußläufige Fortbewegung zu harmonisieren. So weit so gut.

Wieso jedoch "Links" und nicht "rechts"? Ein kurzer Blick in die Ergebnisse einer Suchmaschine führte mich nicht weiter. Man will sicherstellen, dass alle mit dem gleichen Bein anfangen zu gehen, und dieses sei eben das linke.

Schön, schön. Aber warum genau das linke? Wäre es nicht natürlicher - unter der Annahme, dass die meisten Menschen eher Rechtshänder und auch Rechtsfüßer sind - das Gehen mit dem rechten Bein anzufangen?

Darum also die Frage: Gibt es einen sachlichen, praktischen Grund, dass die Militärtradition mit dem linken Bein zu marschieren zu beginnen als günstiger identifiziert hat? Womit sich dann die Formulierung "Links-zwo-drei-vier" abschließend erklären ließe?

---

Nachtrag nach Lektüre der vielen Kommentare:

Je länger ich drüber nachdenke (auch gerade angesichts dessen, dass Thesen zur physischen Bedingtheit des Linksloslaufens auch vielfältig angefochten werden) desto mehr gefällt mir die These, dass "Rechts-zwo-drei-vier" auf Dauer einfach zu anstrengend für die Kehle werden würde - da das r im Standarddeutschen ja nunmal in der Kehle ausgesprochen wird. (Ein paar Dialekte, die es mit der Zunge rollen, waren bei der Ausbildung der allgemeinen deutschen Militärkultur offenbar weniger prägend.)

Wenn an dem Gedanken was dran ist, dann hätten wir hier einen Fall, in dem es die Sprache war, welche die Entscheidung dafür gab, mit welchem Bein beim militärisch-koordinierten Gehen der Anfang gemacht wird. Dann wäre dies aber der vielstimmigen Kritik zum Trotz durchaus eine sprachbezügliche Frage, und es wäre ein schönes Beispiel für eine Sammlung zur reversiven Pragmatik.

Comment: Mit welchem Bein man losläuft, ist jetzt irgendwie keine Frage, die direkt mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat.

Comment: @tofro Da hast Du wohl recht. Es gibt bestimmt eine besser geeignete SE Seite für die Frage.

Comment: Eine bessere Seite für die Frage scheint [SE History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) in Verbindung mit dem Tag [tag:military] zu sein.

Comment: @tofro  Ja, ich verstehe, dass das eine Frage im Grenzbereich zwischen Sprache und außersprachlicher Praxis ist. Aber da schau her: Kommentator Guidot bringt ein Argument für den potentiellen **Einfluss sprachlicher Faktoren** auf die außersprachliche Praxis!

Comment: Ich bin außerdem dafür, die Frage offen zu halten, denn „Wo kommt “Links-zwo-drei-vier” her?“ kann sicher besser beantwortet werden als mit einem Verweis aufs Militär. Wann? Wo? Das betrifft schon die deutsche Sprache. Außerdem: Welche Waffen wurden damals genutzt (das könnte zum Beispiel die recht krude Gleichgewichtstheorie widerlegen).

Comment: [Kommentare in den Chat verschoben](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75214). Bitte nutzt Kommentare nur dazu, die Frage zu verbessern u. Ä. Über Militärgeschichte könnt Ihr gerne im Chat diskutieren.

Comment: Reversive Pragmatik, warum nicht - vielleicht sogar subversive?

Comment: "In einer aktuellen Frage hier" - Link?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper   Hier:   https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/how-often-is-zwo-actually-used-in-place-of-zwei/43251#43251

Answer (score 4):

Es kann auch mit Rechts-Links-Präferenzen wie bei der Rechtshändigkeit zu tun haben. Die meisten Rechtshänder sind ebenfalls Rechtsfüßer. Beim Starten aus einem Startblock etwa drücken sie sich mit dem rechten Fuß ab (bei Linksfüßern umgekehrt). Der erste Schritt ist dann mit dem anderen Fuß, im Fall von Rechtsfüßern also mit links. So gesehen wäre ein erster Schritt mit links für die meisten Menschen in unserer Kultur 'natürlich'.